# How to pass potential error between methods

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to wrap Core Bluetooth Peripheral methods for use in React Native. It's a counterpart for already finished android code, so the API is set.

When I'm calling **CBPeripheralManager.addService**, I need to fulfill or reject a promise, handed from the javascript side.

The problem is, Core Bluetooth doesn't offer a callback for the method, it seems to expect `private func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: Error?)`

I'm new to iOS and Swift so this behavior seems strange to me. Any ideas how can I wrap the function so I can handle the error reporting properly?

Thanks

```
class BLE: NSObject, CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    var advertising: Bool = false
    var servicesMap = Dictionary<String, CBMutableService>()
    var manager: CBPeripheralManager!

    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }

    func addService(promise, serviceUUID) {
        let serviceUUID = CBUUID(string: uuid)
        let service = CBMutableService(type: serviceUUID, primary: true)
        manager.add(service)
    }

    private func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAddService service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            // this should reject the addService promise
            return
        }
        // this should fulfill the promise
    }    
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do when the error happens, exactly? Whatever that is, just do it inside the `if let` block (or call a function from there to handle it and pass the error as a parameter).

Comment: This delegate method is incorrect, and is probably never called. The correct method would be `func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?)`, and it can't be a `private` method. The `addService()` method also isn't valid, but in any case, you would need to store the promise somewhere so you can later fulfill it.

Comment: OK, thanks. But I'm confused, the CBPeripheralManagerDelegate class doesn't have access to it's private functions?

Comment: The class has access to its own private methods, but CBPeripheralManager doesn't have access to its delegate's private methods. It's the manager that calls this method, not the delegate.

Comment: @RobNapier btw xcode is telling me the opposite: "'peripheralManager(_:didAddService:error:)' has been renamed to 'peripheralManager(_:didAdd:error:)'"

Comment: @Eskel Correct. That's the name of the signature I wrote: `func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?)`. The name of that is `peripheralManager(_:didAdd:error:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what the type of `promise` is, but you'll need to store it somewhere, and then fulfill it later. For example, you might add a property:

```
var pendingServices: [CBUUID: Promise] = [:]
```

(I don't know what you're promise type really is here)

Then you'd store it in `addService`:

```
assert(pendingServices[serviceUUID] == nil)
pendingServices[serviceUUID] = promise
```

And later in (the correct; see my comment) delegate method, you'd deal with it:

```
if let promise = pendingServices.removeValue(forKey: service.uuid) {
    promise.fulfill() // Or whatever you do with it
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Seems a little complicated but I guess it's the only way. Too bad apple doesn't provide a way to use a my own custom function. Anyway, thank you!